# Magento 2: What's the difference between Store and Group?

Tags: magento2, database, multistore, programmatically

I want to create a Store programatically, but if it already exists, then return the existing store. So far my code looks like this:

```
private function _getStore($website, $storeName, $storeCode)
{
    try {
        if ($store = $this->storeRepository->get($storeCode)) {
            $groupId = $store->getStoreGroupId();
            return $this->groupRepository->get($groupId);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {}

    if ($website->getId() && !empty($storeName) && !empty($storeCode)) {
        /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Group $group */
        $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
        $group->setWebsiteId($website->getWebsiteId());
        $group->setName($storeName);
        $group->setCode($storeCode);
        $this->groupResourceModel->save($group);
        return $group;
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I create the store for the first time with the store code `my_store` it works fine; I can see that it is logged in `store_group` table.

The second time I run it I am expecting it to give me the store thanks to `$this->storeRepository->get($storeCode)` but it doesn't find the store... I know this because if I remove the `try/catch` it will return an exception:

`The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.`

So how would I check if the store already exists by `code`?

Can someone please explain the difference between store and group?

Answer (score 0):

**How would I check if the store already exists by code?**

Your approach is correct.

Example Code :

```
try {
    $this->storeRepository->get($storeCode);
} catch (NoSuchEntityException $nsee) {
    // Requested store doesn't exist
}
```

**Difference between store and group**

If you will see grid under `Stores -> All Stores`, you will see three columns **Web Site, Store and Store View**
`Web Site` is mapped to the `store_website` table in the database.
`Store` is mapped to the `store_group` table in the database.
`Store View` is mapped to the `store` table in the database.

So, the `$group` is nothing but the `store_group` which is the representation of the `store` entity only.